# bashrc not loaded in /bin/bash shell

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, bashrc

When I ssh into a server (4.3.3-2-ARCH), my .bashrc is not loaded (however, I can load it manually by sourcing it).

I don't have any other files in my home folder, like .profile. The shell is also correct

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

When I login using `ssh -t myserver /bin/bash` , my .bashrc IS loaded correctly.

In SSH verbose mode, I do see that /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc are loaded using the last command. When using the default ssh command, none of them is being loaded...

What should I configure to have .bashrc (and /etc/bash.bashrc) loaded when using the default ssh command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the `~/.bashrc` file is loaded for interactive non-login shells, that's why running `/bin/bash` from ssh works as you expect.

For login shells (amongst others) ~/.bash_profile is read. Typically your `~/.bash_profile` contains something like

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Which ensures that `~/.bashrc` is loaded if your shell is a login shell.

If your `~/.bash_profile` contains the above and `~/.bashrc` is not being loaded you can debug the scripts by using `set -x` as usual.

Comment: I do not have a `~/.bash_profile` ... So, I do need to create it with the above lines in it?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: I created the ~/.bash_profile file and it works... I have installed multiple servers in the past, and I cannot remember that I had to create that to get bashrc working...

Comment: Strange that Ubuntu did not include this files on default. Debian does.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when a user is created it will copy a bunch of files to your new homedirectory (if you chose to create one).

You can check the `/etc/skel` directory for those files. There should be the `.bash_profile` that you expected.

Comment: `/etc/skel` does indeed include `.bash_profile` . So i don't know why I did not have it. I just created my user with `useradd username` ... strange

Comment: were the contents of the file as exspected tho ?

Answer (score 1):

As none of the previous, it seemd that the user didn't have a shell assigned, so it just show the character `$` as prompt.
I had to assign a shell to the user by running the command:

```
sudo usermod --shell /bin/bash username
```

After that, the user automatically logged in with a bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Bash reads group of files depending on the invocation of the shell:

- Login shell: Basically a shell that it is attached to a tty and comes from an authentication process. This kind of shell reads /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile
- Non login - interactive shell: Interactive shells that opens without an authentication process. This kind of shell reads /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc

You can find more information on: man bash , section INVOCATION